# confused: verbs coming after NOT

Tags: grammar

Please Sir, I want to know if it is right to say; "you always get cheated because you have not opened your eyes”.The verb after NOT: is it supposed to be in present or past tense?

Comment: It's not supposed to be either; it's supposed to be the Past Participle. That's the third principal part of the verb: _go, went,** gone**; come, came, **come**; be, was, **been**; have, had, **had**; walk, walked, **walked**_. Often, the past participle has the same form as the past tense form, but not always.

Comment: What form would you use if "not" were absent?

Answer (score 0):

Because "have" precedes "not", you have to have the past participle after "not". However, I would write "You always get cheated because you don't open your eyes."

Comment: Thanks Sir, but why do you prefer “you don't open your eyes” than mine. What's the difference?

Comment: You aren't talking about something that happened only in the past. You're talking about something habitual that isn't tied to a specific time. If I said "I have eaten lunch every day", I'd be talking about my daily habit of eating lunch every day, with no implication that I will continue. If I'm making a general comment about my customary lunch, equally true in the future as in the past, I will say "I eat lunch every day."

Answer (score 0):

As the other members of this English language community have already mentioned, it`s the past particle which is used in your sentence, after the negative particle **not.** A participle that typically expresses completed action, that is traditionally one of the principal parts of the verb, and that is traditionally used in English in the formation of perfect tenses in the active voice and of all tenses in the passive voice.

When we want to form a sentence in the present perfect tense, we to put all parts of a sentence, into a particular order. For example - a personal pronoun (I,you,he,she,it) + have/has (auxiliary verb) + ( the past particle ) verb-ed (or irregular verbs). It`s a standard variant.

Now, a few words about your sentence per se. "You always get cheated because you have not opened your eyes " sounds weird and unnatural because - the first part of this complex sentence speaks about a habitual action, which takes place **always**, whereas the second part of this sentence speaks about the completed action ( one action ) Consequently, the second part of this sentence can not be considered as a meaningful continuation of the first one.  If we say - you always get cheated because you don`t open your eyes, it would make sense, because in this case, these two sentences correlate with each other. The idea presented in the first one, finds its explanation in the second one.

Partly, what we`re dealing with is the verb-tense agreement in complex sentences. If a main clause is in the present simple tense, then subordinate one has also to be in the same tense. For example - I often **walk** to my work because it **helps** me to stay fit.

Take a look at this - https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/tenseconsistency.htm

Answer (score -1):

it should be in pp form. So opened is correct.
However, I think it is better to say "you always get cheated because you don't open your eyes".
Becasue the tense you used is present perfect, Please look into the following link: ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/present-perfect

Comment: Please sir, can you throw more light on it. I want to why it's correct.

Comment: @Masoud please edit your comment into your answer.